# POSTMAN set variable within a XML request Body

Tags: xml, variables, soap, request, postman

I'm trying to make SOAP request with xml using postman, but some of the parameters I want to send must be environment variables I have already stored in other request.

The request Body is something like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="blablabla" xmlns:XXX="http:blablabla/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <XXX:Function>
            <CODE>878734ijHgs</CODE>
            <DISTRIBUTOR>myDistributor</DISTRIBUTOR>
            <MAGICNUMBER>21</MAGICNUMBER>
        </XXX:Function>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The point is that as *MAGICNUMBER* I would like to send a value that I have previously stored as a environment variable, but the syntax {{variable}} doesn't work with XML

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? You can use that syntax within the request body so something else must be happening here. What is returned when you send the request?

Comment: I will copy you the response tomorrow, but basically it doesnt not recognise "<MAGICNUMBER>{{variable}}</MAGICNUMBER>" {{variable}} as an environment varibale and replaces its value

Comment: Hi, I have solved the problem. It was my fault, thanks you Mikhail! closed post

Comment: @GabrielGarcíaGarrido how did you solved it?

Comment: I don't remember so well but I think it was due to I forgot to add  the XXX: before MAGIC NUMBER like <XXX:MAGICNUMBER>{{variable}}</XXX:MAGICNUMBER>. Without adding it, thejaca program that was receiving the request couldn't recognise this parameter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution. Example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="blablabla" xmlns:XXX="http:blablabla/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <XXX:Function>
            <CODE>878734ijHgs</CODE>
            <DISTRIBUTOR>myDistributor</DISTRIBUTOR>
            <MAGICNUMBER>{{variable}}</MAGICNUMBER>
        </XXX:Function>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same issue for a few minutes. In my case I added a new environment variable but **I didn't save the environment**. It was still opened in a tab nearby with orange circle at the right side. After saving the environment by pressing [Ctrl+S] on environment tab, variable started to resolve properly.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue a few moments ago. In my case, I added the value only to the **Initial value**, but we also need to add the value to the **Current value**.

Comment: Where does that fit in the question?

Comment: Variables in XML work just as usual. So, if it is not working, it's something else. I answered with an alternative of what someone might be doing wrong that it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue a few moments ago. In my case, I added a space before the variable name when i am using in request body. stupid but true :D